# android ndk multitouch?

Tags: android, events, android-ndk, java-native-interface, multi-touch

im writing an application that uses only native code.
So is it possible to get multitouch events in ndk?
I feel like ive serched the whole web, but without finding anything!

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is.
You can check example called `native-activity` to see how to get input events. Look for `engine_handle_input` function. `AInputEvent_getType` function returns type of event. If it is `AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION` then using `AKeyEvent_getAction` function you can get different information about touch event. Use the `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_MASK`, `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK`, `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` and `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_UP` enums in same way you use them in Java API: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!
I didn't knew what the pointer events are :D