# How to handle multitouch event in android using ndk?

Tags: android

1. New for ndk...

   2.
   would like to know how to handle touch event in android for ndk based app.

Comment: Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500825/android-ndk-multitouch

Comment: yes...but that is not clear..need more reference ..